# How does [attributename] work in MapServer templates?

Tags: postgis, mapserver

I have a template file that contains this line:

```
[item name="geographicalName"], [geographicalName]
```

The output is

```
π. Σπερχειός, [geographicalName]
```

That is, the tag `[geographicalName]` is output as is, it is not substituted.
Shouldn't it have the same result as the first tag in this case? Otherwise what does [the documentation](https://mapserver.org/mapfile/template.html) mean with the following?

> [attribute name],[attrribute name_esc],[attribute item name_raw]
>
> Attribute name from the data table of a queried layer. Only attributes for the active query layers are accessible. Case must be the same as what is stored in the data file. ArcView, for example, uses all caps for shapefile field names. Available only when processing query results.
>
> By default the attributes are encoded especially for HTML representation. In addition the escaped version (for use in URLs) as well as the raw data is available.

Comment: I have no experience with Mapserver, but does `[attribute geographicalName]` work?

Comment: Good suggestion, @Stefan, but no, it doesn't work.

Comment: What format is your data in? Is there a column called "geographicalName"? What do the values look like?

Answer (score 4):

The problem was that PostgreSQL/PostGIS, which is my backend, automatically converts `geographicalName` to `geographicalname` (unless you quote it) when the table is created. Using `[geographicalname]` instead of `[geographicalName]` works alright.